# Custom Headers on Restler Get

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using [Dan Wrong's Restler](https://github.com/danwrong/restler/) for Node Express to connect to an API. One of my endpoints requires a custom header is sent, but I'm having no luck in sending this:-

```
    restler.get('api.co.uk/user', 
{ username: 'xx', password: 'xx' }, 
{ headers: { 'token': cookie }})
                .on('complete', function(user) {
                    res.render('dashboard.ejs', { user: user });
                })
                .on('error', function(error) {
                    res.render('500.ejs', { error: error });
                })
```

I've tried variations of how to include the headers - but nothing seems to work, the header never seems to pass. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this please?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
restler.get('http://api.co.uk/user', {
  query   : { username: 'xx', password: 'xx' },
  headers : { token: cookie }
}).on(...)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work either :s For some reason, the custom header never gets passed. Code is exactly as above ^^ ?

Comment: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5586694) a standalone test that logs which headers the built-in HTTP server is receiving from the Restler client (which includes the `token` header in my case). Tested with Restler@2.0.1, Express@3.2.4 and Node@0.10.5. Perhaps your API endpoint is case-sensitive w.r.t. headers, so try `Token` instead of `token`.

Comment: Hey @robertklep, unsure what was wrong the first time, but with a more thorough re-write of the code based on your gist, it's working. Many many thanks :) Appreciated. +1 for continued assistance.